# Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to global function

Tags: swift, toast

I have made a Toast function as below

CommonFunctions.swift

```
import UIKit

func showToast(toastTitle: String, toastText: String, type : ToastType, position : ToastPosition = .center, style : ToastStyle = .defaultToast){
    
    if (style == .defaultToast) {
        
        if let foundView = topVC?.view.viewWithTag(toastTagNumber) {
            foundView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        toastTimer?.invalidate()
        toastTimer = nil
        
        if let currentView : UIView = topVC?.view {
            
            let toastView : UIView = UIView()
            currentView.addSubview(toastView)
            toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            toastView.tag = toastTagNumber
            toastView.backgroundColor = AppColors.topBarBackgroundColor
            toastView.fillHorizontally(padding: 10*iPhoneFactorX)
            toastView.Bottom == currentView.Bottom - (bottomBarInnerHeight + safeAreaBottomHeight + (10*iPhoneFactorX))
            toastView.addRadius(radius: 15*iPhoneFactorX)
            
            let toast_headerLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
            toastView.addSubview(toast_headerLabel)
            toast_headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            toast_headerLabel.Top == toastView.Top + (10*iPhoneFactorX)
            toast_headerLabel.fillHorizontally(padding: 5*iPhoneFactorX)
            toast_headerLabel.adjustDefaultLabel(fontColor: AppColors.whiteColor_FFFFFF, fontSize: 15, fontType: .bold)
            toast_headerLabel.text = toastTitle
            toast_headerLabel.isHidden = toastTitle.isEmpty
            toast_headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
            
            let toast_textLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
            toastView.addSubview(toast_textLabel)
            toast_textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            toast_textLabel.Top == toast_headerLabel.Bottom + (10*iPhoneFactorX)
            toast_textLabel.fillHorizontally(padding: 5*iPhoneFactorX)
            toast_textLabel.adjustDefaultLabel(fontColor: AppColors.whiteColor_FFFFFF, fontSize: 14)
            toast_textLabel.text = toastText
            toast_textLabel.textAlignment = .center
            
            toastView.Bottom == toast_textLabel.Bottom - (10*iPhoneFactorX)
            
            toastTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(toastDismissDuration), repeats: false) { (Timer) in
                hideToast()
            }
            
            let toast_button : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            toastView.addSubview(toast_button)
            toast_button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            toast_button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            toast_button.fillContainer()
            toast_button.backgroundColor = .clear
            // problem comes here
            toast_button.addTarget(currentView, action: #selector(clickedDefaultToast), for: .touchUpInside)
            toastView.addSubview(toast_button)
            
        }
        
    }
}

func clickedDefaultToast() {
    print("fapa=clickedDefaultToast==0001")
    
}
```

Calling it as below.

```
showToast(toastTitle: "error", toastText: "toast text comes here", type: .error)
```

Toast is showing and goes away in 3 seconds which is not an issue.

I want to remove Toast if anyone click on it. So I add a button. However issue coming when adding target on it.

Error I get is as below.

```
Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to global function 'clickedDefaultToast()'
```

If I add `@objc` for function, I get error as

```
@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes
```

How can I achieve this to dismiss when clicked?

Comment: Don't `addTarget` if you don't actually have a target. [`addAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/3600490-addaction) instead. Then you can pass a closure that calls `clickedDefaultToast()`.

Comment: @Sweeper : Works fine... just a loss is it need iOS 14+ which is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Targets respond to selectors.* It doesn't make sense to pass a selector of `clickedDefaultToast`, when the target `currentView` doesn't respond to it, regardless of whether Swift *allows* you to do this.

Selectors are usually methods declared in a class (and instances of that class would respond to the selector), and so Swift has the `#selector(...)` syntax to let you get a `Selector` from an *instance* method.

If you just want to call a global function when the button is clicked, [`addAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/3600490-addaction) instead of `addTarget`. This allows you to just pass a Swift closure instead of a selector.

```
toast_button.addAction(UIAction { clickedDefaultToast() }, for: .touchUpInside)
```

Otherwise, you would need to change your design to use target-action pairs. The usage could be something like:

```
// declare a Toast property at the class level
let toast = Toast()

// in some method...
toast.showToast(...)
```

You'd move `showToast` and `clickedDefaultToast` into a new `Toast` class. You would use `self` as the target of the button, and `self` can respond to the `clickedDefaultToast` selector.

In my opinion, this design is better because you can also store the currently displayed toast `UIView` in the `Toast` instance, so dismissing it is trivial - just remove the `UIView` from its superview. With your current design, finding the currently displayed toast would be rather hard.